# Проблема подключения к Wi-Fi без интернета или пасхалка 7 версии андроид

Tags: android, wifi

Добрый день. Написал приложение android, которое подсоединяется к прибору по Wi-Fi и общается с ним. Прибор раздает Wi-Fi без соединения с интернетом. Всё работало хорошо, проверял на рабочем девайсе с версией - 5.0 .
Однако, решил поставить приложения на своей девайс с версией 7.1.1 и тут возникла проблема.

При подключении к данной сети Wi-FI, приложение не хотело открывать сокет. Оказалось, что система выдает сообщение в notification о том, что "подключенная сеть Wi-Fi не имеет доступ к интернету". Чтобы сокет открылся, пользователь должен зайти в это оповещение и подтвердить, что он хочет подключиться именно к этой, "безинтернетной" сети.

**Собственно вопрос:** как программно "перескочить" данное уведомление и подключиться насильно или хотя бы вывести какой-то диалог с предложением именно в приложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это началось еще с Андроид 6.
Попробуйте как-то так:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_detection_enabled", 0);
```

Comment: Я даже не видел инфы по этому поводу, где можно почитать? В офф документации в обычных пермишинах такого нет..)

Comment: Вот тут обсуждали: https://github.com/eryngii-mori/android-developer-preview/issues/2218

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомлюсь.
Интересно, а можно ли программно выводить диалог о "подтверждении подключении к сети Wi-Fi без интернета" при включении приложения?

Comment: Как я понимаю, это все ради безопасности, чтобы без ведома пользователя приложения не коннектились к непонятным сетям не понятно зачем. И система тут себя ведет как "сам себе хозяин".

Comment: Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону создания собственных WIFI profile, или как это называется. Пользователь один раз откликнет, что разрешает его создать, возможно потом система добрее будет :)